# QFT Perturbative analysis of multiple atom-level quantum computers close to each other

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-computer, feynman-diagrams

Following up on [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162833/10531), I'm wondering about electromagnetic interactions perturbation expansions close to a "black-box" quantum computer and modularity of Feynman diagrams in general. Let me describe a little better what I have in mind

Suppose you can do a pretty simply quantum computer that is a physical system of quantum size. For example, it could be a quantum computer made of a single-atom, or a single-molecule. The point is, that the small quantum computer normal usage is by providing some $|in \rangle $ state, and wait some $|out \rangle$ state out of it. Usually, the input and output states are on-shell asymptotic states, and in this regime, the quantum computer works as expected and does some useful computation.

But if two or more of these quantum computers are close to each other, and interacting, one could attempt a perturbative expansion, but this time, in a particular diagram where the output of computer $C_1$ is fed as a input leg to the computer $C_2$, the line would be an *off-shell* parameter

What I consider as an intriguing possibility, but it seems also far-fetched, technologically speaking to achieve at the moment, is to take advantage of the fact that the lines connecting outputs and input can be off-shell, and consider space-like quantum feedback loops like shown in this diagram:

[image: a space-like feedback loop between the inputs and outputs of two quantum computers]

Now, this diagram is supposed to represent a term on a long series of perturbative diagrams each contributing some amplitude.

Considering the small overall amplitude contributed by this diagram to the normal operation of two such computers. This amplitude might be small, but finite.

**my (concrete) question, for the purposes of this post is how correct are the following two assertions:**

> **1)** If one could carry some useful computation on the feedback loop
>   mode that couldn't be carried in the other tree-level processes, that
>   "special" computation (to be specified in the next paragraph) will only happen at a probability rate that is
>   roughly proportional to the square of the loop amplitude
>   $\phi^{*}\phi$.
>
> **2)** Because of **1)**, most of the time, the system will behave as two
>   quantum computers operating on  their own, but a fraction
>   $\phi^{*}\phi$ of the outputs, will be two quantum computers in a
>   model of computation equivalent to a *closed timelike curve computer*.
>   According to [Deutsch and others](http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/ctc.pdf), CTC computers have NP-complete
>   as their complexity class

Comment: If I have penetrated the unnecessarily confusing particle-physics language correctly, you are basically asking if it is possible to use the output state of one quantum computer as the input state of another quantum computer, without making any measurements on the state first. Is that correct? If so, then obviously yes, but it depends on the implementation.

Comment: yeah, but you are missing the part that I consider most important: Since not only no measurement is performed, and additionally the qcomputers are very close, the line connecting input and output states should be "off-shell" states. That is, *the line connecting those two qcomputers* **are loosely constrained by an energy-momentum relationship**, which will manifest by a propagator that is wider and softer than a delta

Comment: Hi diffeomorphism, I did understand the emphasis on off-shell states. Think in terms of the Feynman sum-over-paths prescription. This says that between observations you must sum over all possible trajectories of field configurations consistent with the observed outcome.  "Off-shell" simply means summing over paths in 4-momentum space. So it seems that you are attributing more significance to the concept of "off-shell legs" than there really is: it literally just means that no observation has occurred in the context of relativistic QFT.

Comment: Put it another way, the intermediate step you are describing (taking the output from one computer and putting it into another quantum computer), could equally be described as an intermediate step in a larger quantum computer consisting of both black boxes. So you see that there is nothing additional that can be performed with this set up than with a normal quantum computer. Moreover, it doesn't matter whether the computers are macroscopic or microscopic. If the particles are well isolated in between the computers, they will be off mass-shell.

Comment: It may be simply that you are interested in a more general question, namely whether it is possible to perform additional quantum information tasks with a quantum computer when the physical substrate comprises light particles at relativistic energies? I think that is an interesting question, although I wouldn't expect anything more interesting in the context of quantum computation per se. You could look up the work of Ivette Fuentes who is interested in similar topics.

Comment: @MarkMitchison, I edited the question with more concrete thinking, and a more concrete question